# Extract list of SharePoint lists and libraries

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, powershell, libraries

i am using below code the extract all lists and libraries under a site collection . However i need to get the lists and libraries URL too. all other properties return coorect information except URL, its just empty!! Can you please help?

```
(get-spsite -identity http://uatsp11/sites/harristest).allwebs.lists | select  title, URL ,  LastItemModifiedDate, itemcount | Expo-Csv -Path C:\temp.csv
```

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You could use [DefaultViewUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.splist?view=sharepoint-server) property.

```
(get-spsite -identity http://sp13).allwebs.lists | select  title, DefaultViewUrl ,  LastItemModifiedDate, itemcount
```

Update:

```
(get-spsite -identity http://sp13).allwebs.lists | select {$_.ParentWeb.Url}, title, DefaultViewUrl ,  LastItemModifiedDate, itemcount
```

Comment: @harris - The above should work as it displays the URL of the default view. There is no property called "URL" and hence returning empty.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it helped me a lot, is there any way i can add associated site to each list and libraries too?

Comment: Check whether my update meets your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Lee_MSFT, it solved my problems

Comment: You could accept it as answer so it may help others.